# How to add conditional statement related to configurable product and the quantity of options

Tags: product, ce-1.8.0.0, attribute-options

I am trying to add a condition statement to add certain text in front of price. I've got the code to check whether it's configurable product or not:

```
if ($_product->getData('type_id') == 'configurable') {
    // ...
}
```

*How can I add another code to check if the attribute options are more than one?*

For example,

```
attribute name: color,
dropdown options: green, yellow, blue...
```

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to check if there are more than 1 "selectable attributes" like color, manufacturer, etc., or there are more than 1 "selectable options" for 1 attribute like green, yellow, blue for color?

Comment: thanks for your reply. i'd like to check if there are more than 1 selectable option for 1 attribute. meaning, if there are more than 1 color available. as i only have 1 attribute 'color', no size etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the number of options available for the configurable attributes of a given product try below code.

> UPDATED CODE:

```
  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

if($product->isConfigurable()) {
    $attrs  = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);

    foreach($attrs as $attr) {
        if(trim($attr['attribute_code']) == 'color') {
            $options    = $attr['values'];

            // Check the color attribute options count is greater than 1.
            if(count($options) > 1) {
                // Do something.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. the concept is closed to what i want to achieve, i want add a condition for all configurable products which have more than 1 selectable options under attribute 'color'. i am not an expert of php coder, hopefully someone can help. thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer